# NSMutableArray releasing / destruction

Tags: objective-c, memory-management, nsmutablearray

The following code in my function (run in a loop) is causing my program to use more and more memory until it crashes. What am I doing wrong?

```
- (void) processTrackValues:(NSMutableArray*) tags {  
    NSImage* trackArt = [tags objectAtIndex:5];  
    NSMutableArray* tempArtArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];  
    [tempArtArray addObject:trackArt];  
    [tempArtArray release];  
}
```

I also tried:

```
- (void) processTrackValues:(NSMutableArray*) tags {  
    NSImage* trackArt = [tags objectAtIndex:5];  
    NSMutableArray* tempArtArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];  
    [tempArtArray addObject:trackArt];  
    [trackArt release];  
    [tempArtArray release];  
}
```

Edit: Here is more information on the surrounding code. I have also added more code to the sample for a bigger picture.

- `trackArt` is an `NSImage` pointer to one of the arguments to this function.
- The `NSImage` object that `trackArt` points to is created outside of this function.
- I am allocating and releasing `tempArtArray` each iteration of the loop (since the function is called for each iteration of the loop)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

can you post the surrounding loop code to help get a bigger picture?

Do you allocate and release `tempArtArray` for every loop iteration? If so can you instead allocate it once outside of the loop and reuse it?

How are the `trackArt` objects created?

Comment: Agreed, post more of the loop.

Comment: I have posted more of the surrounding loop and added edits to the question with more information. Hope this helps.

Comment: I don't see a loop there, only a method definition.

Answer (score 2):

The (now posted twice) method is nonsense.  At the end of the method, the method has accomplished exactly nothing.

Post the real code.

In particular, how are you actually creating the `NSImage` instances?  How do you know that this particular method is causing the bloat and eventual crash?